# How to Increment/Decrement count in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I need to use count with increment value and I have using below code But some how it's not working.

```
{% assign count = 0 %}

{% for something in somethings %}
  {% count++ %}
{% endfor %}

{{ count }}
```

Answer (score 1):

please replace

```
{% count++ %}
```

to

```
{% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}
```